# Hero card buttons are represented as bullets after deploying it to azure

Tags: node.js, azure, bots, botframework, chatbot

I have developed a chat bot in node.js and deployed it to Microsoft Azure. I have done debugging locally using bot framework channel emulator and everything was perfect along with two buttons which I have added to a Hero Card. But after deploying the same code to Azure, those two buttons were converted to two bullets.

Code:

```
bot.dialog('/secondaryTrigger', [
  function (session) {
  var hCard = new builder.HeroCard(session)
          .title('Hi '+session.userData.splittedName[0]+'!')
        .text('Select Your Billability Please')
          .buttons([

              builder.CardAction.imBack(session, 'Billable', 'Billable'),
              builder.CardAction.imBack(session, 'Non-Billable', 'Non-Billable')
          ]);

          var msg = new builder.Message(session).attachments([hCard]);
          session.send(msg);
          session.beginDialog('/billability');
      }]);
```

References:

While debugging locally

[image: Image:]

After Deploying to Azure

[image: Image:]

I can not find the justification/reason behind it. Anybody faced the same issue?

Comment: Are you testing the bot remotely from the emulator, or are you using one of the channels to test it?

Comment: Can you post your code for the Hero Card? What channel are you using?

Comment: @stuartd: Bot is running on localhost, I am debugging it locally using the emulator.

Comment: @NilsW: Updated

Comment: So it's changed while running it locally only because you deployed it? That is odd.

Comment: @stuartd: yeah. working fine when running locally. Gets bullet after deploying to azure!

Comment: @All: I know this will sound strange but I wanna ask does azure has any issue with hero cards?

Comment: @SouravDebnath How are you viewing the card in the "After deploying to Azure" screenshot?  Are you viewing the card on the Emulator, Skype, Slack, MS Teams.... what channel?

Comment: @NilsW: "After deploying to Azure" screenshot is: after publishing bot to Azure, using the end point url I am interacting with my bot. And I am using web chat only..

Comment: As far as I understand your first image is in localhost with emulator, the 2nd pointing to your deployed version and using webchat?

Comment: @NicolasR: Yes, absolutely.

Comment: @All: Found this on git: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/335

Comment: @All: Hi, I have resolved this issue! Actually in the latest release of Bot framework, you have to check in the check box named "Enable Preview" in WebChat settings. It's working fine now! Thanks all!